# PHP - read date results and add style at different

Tags: php

I have the following set of results from a query:

```
name        date_added
----        ---------
dan         15/11/2012
jane        15/11/2012
ted         14/11/2012
larry       13/11/2012
corben      13/11/2012
```

These results are from a simple MySQL query and I display the results e.g.

```
while($users = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $users[name].' -- '.$users[date_added];

}
```

This produces a simple list e.g.

```
dan    --     15/11/2012
jane   --     15/11/2012
ted    --     14/11/2012
larry  --     13/11/2012
corben --     13/11/2012
```

What I want to do is the head the results with the different dates, starting with the first one, e.g.

```
15/11/2012
dan    --     15/11/2012
jane   --     15/11/2012

14/11/2012
ted    --     14/11/2012

13/11/2012
larry  --     13/11/2012
corben --     13/11/2012
```

The dates change daily as this is a living document so nothing is hard coded.

Is there a simple and efficient way to do this within the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array();
while($users = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $key = $users['date_added'];
  if (!isset($dates[$key])) $dates[$key] = array();
  $dates[$key][] = $users[name].' -- '.$users[date_added];
}

// free mysql results
// then iterate $dates to print

foreach ($dates as $date=>$arr)
{
  echo $date.'<br/>'.implode($arr).'<br/><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in an array with the date as key and then display all of them like so:

```
$users = array();
while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!isset($users[$user['date_added'])) $users[$user['date_added']] = array();
    $users[$user['date_added']][] = $user['name'];
}
foreach ($users as $date => $names) {
    echo $date . '<br />';
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo $name . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

You can also change the query so that it orders them on date, loop through the results and every time the date is different from the iteration before that you print the date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mySQL DISTINCT... Fx:

```
$dates = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT date_added FROM your_table ORDER BY date_added ASZ");

$user_date = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dates)) {
  array_push($user_date, $row['date_added']);
}

foreach ($user_date as $date) {
    echo $date . '<br />';
    $users = ("SELECT name, date_added FROM your_table WHERE date_added = '$date' ORDER BY date_added ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
      echo $row['name'] . ' -- ' . $row['date_added'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```